# Exportar usuários e permissões do MySQL para outro servidor

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou fazendo outro servidor com os mesmos bancos de dados do server anterior (Já migrei os bancos de dados) e gostaria de migrar os usuários e permissões deste server anterior para o novo server de uma vez só, é possível? como se faz?

Comment: Server ou banco de dados (você marcou somente tags de bancos de dados)

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/8860/how-can-i-export-the-privileges-from-mysql-and-then-import-to-a-new-server